# grid.text in a ggplot give an error in plot_grid

Tags: r, ggplot2, grid, cowplot

I am trying to use the `plot_grid` function from `cowplot` R package to put two plots together. However, I was getting the below error:

> Error in switch(x[[2]][[1]]$name, C_abline = C_abline(x[[2]]),
>   C_plot_new = C_plot_new(x[[2]]),  :    EXPR must be a length 1 vector

Therefore, testing both graphics I discovery that the error came from a `ggplot` which I used grid_text. Thus, in my example here I included only one plot. With the below you can reproduce the problem:

```
library(cowplot)
library(ggplot2)
library(ggforce)
library(grid)


### Example
circles <- as.data.frame(cbind(c(0.5, 1.5, 2.5), c(1, 2, 1), c(0.2, 0.2, 0.2)))

# Behold the some circles
ggplot() + geom_circle(aes(x0=V1, y0=V2, r=V3, fill=c("red", "blue", "green")), data=circles)+
  theme_bw() + ylab(expression(symbol('\253'))) + xlab(expression(symbol('\253')))+ theme(legend.position="none",
                                                                                          axis.title.x=element_text(size = 50),
                                                                                          axis.text.x=element_blank(),
                                                                                          axis.ticks.x=element_blank(),
                                                                                          axis.title.y=element_text(size = 50),
                                                                                          axis.text.y=element_blank(),
                                                                                          axis.ticks.y=element_blank()) 

grid.text("Distinct", x = unit(0.04, "npc"), y = unit(0.80, "npc"))

exP <- recordPlot()

plot_grid(exP)
```

I would be glad to receive any idea how to use plot_grid on that kind of object (ggplot + grid_text).

Comment: The other plot is working without any problems. That's why I only include one for simplicity. I will clarify on that.

Comment: Why not using `grid.arrange` ?

Comment: Because it give this error: Error in gList(list(grobs = list(list(x = 0.5, y = 0.5, width = 1, height = 1,  : 
  only 'grobs' allowed in "gList"

Comment: The error is caused by whatever it is that `recordPlot()` does. I recommend not to use it, in particular when you're only working with grid graphics, as is the case here. See my proposed answer for alternatives.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggforce)
library(grid)
library(gridExtra)


### Example
circles <- as.data.frame(cbind(c(0.5, 1.5, 2.5), c(1, 2, 1), c(0.2, 0.2, 0.2)))

# Behold the some circles
p1 <- ggplot() + 
  geom_circle(aes(x0=V1, y0=V2, r=V3, fill=c("red", "blue", "green")), data=circles)+
  theme_bw() + ylab(expression(symbol('\253'))) + xlab(expression(symbol('\253')))+ 
  theme(legend.position="none",
        axis.title.x=element_text(size = 50),
        axis.text.x=element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.x=element_blank(),
        axis.title.y=element_text(size = 50),
        axis.text.y=element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.y=element_blank()) 

print(p1)
grid.text("Distinct", x = unit(0.04, "npc"), y = unit(0.80, "npc"))
p2 <- grid.grab()

grid.arrange(p1,p2, nrow=1)
```

[image]

Comment: Importantly, this answer works because `recordPlot()` was replaced by `grid.grab()`, not because `plot_grid()` was replaced by `grid.arrange()`. The problem is in `recordPlot()`. Once you've captured the text grob with `grid.grab()`, `plot_grid()` can handle it just fine.

Answer (score 2):

Your example should work, and the fact that it doesn't is a bug that I need to look into.

However, even if it did work, I'd recommend against it. I haven't had good experiences with recorded plots, and in general doing the whole round trip of first drawing the plot and then capturing it seems awkward and error-prone to me. I suggests three alternatives of doing what you want to do. They all give you the same final result.

First, you can use grid graphics to combine a ggplot and any other grob into a combined grob, which you can then hand to `plot_grid()`:

```
library(cowplot)
library(ggplot2)
library(ggforce)
library(grid)

# Plot of mpg data, to use in plot_grid below
pmpg <- ggplot(mpg, aes(x=cty, y=hwy)) + geom_point()

# Plot with circles
circles <- as.data.frame(cbind(c(0.5, 1.5, 2.5), c(1, 2, 1), c(0.2, 0.2, 0.2)))
pcircles <- ggplot() + 
  geom_circle(aes(x0=V1, y0=V2, r=V3, fill=c("red", "blue", "green")),
              data=circles) +
  theme_bw() + ylab(expression(symbol('\253'))) + 
  xlab(expression(symbol('\253'))) + 
  theme(legend.position="none",
        axis.title.x=element_text(size = 50),
        axis.text.x=element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.x=element_blank(),
        axis.title.y=element_text(size = 50),
        axis.text.y=element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.y=element_blank()) 

# text grob
gtext <- grid::textGrob("Distinct", x = unit(0.04, "npc"), y = unit(0.80, "npc"))

# make combined grob
gcombined <- grid::grobTree(ggplotGrob(pcircles), gtext)

plot_grid(pmpg, gcombined)
```

The result:

[image]

Second, I wrote the `ggdraw()` function and related functions to make it easy to combine ggplot objects and other grid objects. E.g., you can draw your text grob onto the plot like this:

```
pcombined <- ggdraw(pcircles) + draw_grob(gtext)
plot_grid(pmpg, gcombined)
```

The result looks exactly the same as before.

And, if all you want to do is draw some text, you can also use `draw_text()` instead of `draw_grob()`:

```
pcombined <- ggdraw(pcircles) + draw_text("Distinct", x = 0.04, y = 0.8)
plot_grid(pmpg, gcombined)
```

Finally, I'd like to point out that the [solution by Marco Sandri](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46796179/4975218), which uses `grid.grab()`, also works with `plot_grid()` instead of `grid.arrange()`.